# Finding a number of unique words in a line of text file

Tags: python, text

I would like to create a Python program to find the unique words in a line in text file.

The text file "details" has following lines

```
My name is crazyguy
i am studying in a college and i travel by car
my brother brings me food for eating and we will go for shopping after food.
```

it must return output as

```
4
10 #(since i is repeated)
13 #(Since food and for are repeated)
```

If the code works, will it work the same way for bigger text files in mining the data?

Comment: I would suggest you look into NLTK, a plain script in python will not be efficient at dealing with larger files.

Comment: Easy. For every line, create a set container. Tokenize the line (based on whitespace, for example), and throw each token into the set. Then, count the number of elements in that set.

Comment: @Leb - NTLK doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, yes here of course not. But he did mention *If the code works, will it work the same way for bigger text files in mining the data?* That's why I suggested NLTK. He can have one of those MANY answers posted here but they won't be efficient for later on.

Comment: It's just that it doesn't look like the program is trying to analyze the whole file. It only needs to deal with one line at a time.

Comment: I agree with @TigerhawkT3; also I don't even know why NTLK should be faster in this case. AFAIK, NTLK is but python, and `set()` is probably the very fastest way of hashing and unifying a python list; `split()` will be very hard to implement faster in NTLK.

Comment: Again, *in this case*, I'm only *suggesting* for future use. No need to have a small file for one or two line, then having to change it when your data gets larger, IMO.

Comment: The issue is that the OP shouldn't have to make any changes for large files, as far as I can tell. The simple solutions scale just fine for this.

Comment: Then [data-mining] and [text-mining] are invalid tags for this then. I'm not disagreeing with the answers given, but it seems to me the OP is looking for something more. It started off with unique words but (unless those tags are incorrect) he'll need more than `line.split()`.

Comment: @Leb, that's an excellent point. I've removed the misleading tags.

Comment: Even if the data gets larger, his requirement naturally asks for processing of a fraction of the file at a time (i.e. one line at a time). You can already scale that easily with vanilla Python, even on multi-gigabyte files. (It might get tricky if you have ONE line that is like 10GB long).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use set traverse through all the line split to create lsit and make it to set to find unique value and find it's count

```
with open("filename","r") as inp:
     for line in inp:
         print len(set(line.split()))
```

Comment: You've got a `;` before your `:`, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('details.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(len(set(line.split())))
```

Comment: @Vignesh - Yep; not much room for unique algorithms here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Is that a challenge?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ list comprehension can be used but it is unwanted here and if you have any nice method would be nice to see

Comment: Yeah, I was considering putting it into a generator and unpacking it with `*` into Python 3's `print()`, but the regular way scales better.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: admittedly, I don't have a more performant approach. But... lemme think about that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: See [this figment of my laziness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31348420/4433386).

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole world of solutions that are worse than TigerhawkT3's/Vignesh Kalai's solution. For comparison:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("len(set(string.split()))", "string=\""+string+"\"")
9.243406057357788
```

is their implementation. I actually had high hopes for this one:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("len(set(map(hash,string.split())))", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
14.462514877319336
```

because here, the `set` is only built over the hashes. (And because the hashes are numbers, they don't need to be hashed themselves, or so I hoped. Type handling in `set` probably still kills me; otherwise, in theory, the number of hashes calculated would be the same as in the best solution, but there might have been less awkward PyObject juggling underneath. I was wrong.)

So I tried dealing with the hashes in numpy; first with the raw strings, for comparison:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("len(numpy.unique(string.split()))", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
33.38827204704285
>>> timeit.timeit("len(numpy.unique(map(hash,string.split())))", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
37.22595286369324
>>> timeit.timeit("len(numpy.unique(numpy.array(map(hash,string.split()))))", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
36.20353698730469
```

Last resort: A Counter might simply circumvent the reduction step. But then again, Python strings are just PyObjects and you really don't gain by having a `dict` instead of a `set`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("max(Counter(string.split()).values())==1", "from collections import Counter\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
46.88196802139282
>>> timeit.timeit("len(Counter(string.split()))", "from collections import Counter\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
44.15947103500366
```

By the way: Half of the time of the best solution goes into splitting:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("string.split()", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
4.552565097808838
```

and, counter-intuitively, that time even increases if you specify that you *only* want to split along spaces (and not all typical delimiters):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("string.split(' ')", "import numpy\nstring=\""+string+"\"")
4.713452100753784
```